# How to list current directory files through socket API?

Tags: python, sockets

So right now I have a simple FTP system to transfer files.

But I am confused about how I would run commands on the server machine from a client machine.

How would I open a terminal on the server machine from my client machine to use commands such as ls or mkdir or cd? Or can I do this straight from Socket Programming

Answer (score 0):

You could use the python module `subprocess`. (https://pymotw.com/2/subprocess/)

For example, assuming you have a client/server 'dialogue' set up using sockets, you could do something like this:

**client.py**

```
# assume 's' is your socket already connected to the server

# prompt the user for a command to send
cmd = raw_input("user > ")
s.send(cmd) # send your command to the server
# let's say you input 'ls -la'
```

You could put the above code inside a loop that only breaks when you enter 'quit' or something, to continually send and receive commands. You would need a loop or something similar on the server side too, to continually accept and return the output from your commands. You could also use threads.

**server.py**

```
# on the server side do this
# s is again your socket bound to a port
# but we're on the server side this time!

from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

cmd = s.recv(1024)
# cmd now has 'ls -la' assigned to it
# parse it a bit
cmd = cmd.split() # to get ['ls', '-la']

# now we execute the command on the server with subprocess
p = Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE)
result = p.communicate() 
# result is, in this case, the listing of files in the current directory

s.send(result[0]) # result[0] should be a str

# you now make sure to receive your result on the client
```

**Note:** I think a newer version is `subprocess32`, but all methods are the same as far as I remember.

Comment: Is there an example code you have to execute it over a host?

Comment: Do you know how to send data between client/server using sockets?

Comment: Yes, i already did that, but i have no experience with sub process

Comment: Does that make any sense?

Comment: Yep! Thanks for the help. going to test this on Mac

Comment: Ok so I tried this, and it gave me an error on s.send(result) which said it cannot return a string or buffer, not tuple

Comment: my apologies, I edited my post. It was returning a tuple, from which you only want the first element. So the line should be(as I've edited above), s.send(result[0]) which is a string

Comment: you could also just do result = communicate()[0] and then s.send(result)

Comment: If you found this helped you solve your issue,  please consider 'accepting' it